# How to add menu and navigation to all the activities?

Tags: android

I do not know how to add navigation drawer, menu to all the activity, but I how to create menu, navigation drawer for one activity. I am beginner.

Comment: please explain the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want to add navigation drawer and menu in all screens in your application.

To do that, you don't need to create navigation drawer at each activity, you should use navigation drawer with fragments not activities, just create one activity with menu and navigation drawer and replace fragments when you need to change the screen.

I think this tutorial would be useful for you :

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

[Create a navigation drawer  - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer)